# Run a powershell line to a specific process ID

Tags: vb.net, windows, powershell, autodesk

I am trying to write a form, where I have the option to open an exe with different sessions, each session with 2 cores. The program I'm trying to execute is Revit 2015. I have figured a way to include it in my app, Revit 2015 work perfectly with:

cmd.exe /c start "Revit" /affinity XX "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2015\Revit.exe

In my visual project it would be like this:

```
Private Sub GPG4B1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GPG4B1.Click

If Not Me.RadioButton1.Checked And Not Me.RadioButton2.Checked Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please select a Revit version")
Else
    If IsNothing(Me.ComboBoxGP.SelectedItem) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select the Cores")
    Else
        If Me.RadioButton1.Checked And Me.ComboBoxGP.Text = "1 Core" Then
            Shell("cmd.exe /c start ""Revit"" /affinity 00000001 ""C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2015\Revit.exe""")
        End If

        If Me.RadioButton1.Checked And Me.ComboBoxGP.Text = "2 Cores" Then
            Shell("cmd.exe /c start ""Revit"" /affinity 9 ""C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2015\Revit.exe""")
        End If

        If Me.RadioButton1.Checked And Me.ComboBoxGP.Text = "3 Cores" Then
            Shell("cmd.exe /c start ""Revit"" /affinity 15 ""C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2015\Revit.exe""")
        End If
```

So a user would have to chose the version of Revit with a radio button, and from a combo box, he would have to chose the set of cores he would like to use. For some reason, this doesn't cut it with Revit 2016! Using the same command line would just end up doing nothing to the affinity of the session of Revit where I am trying to pass that command line.

But the internet was generous, so I found a workaround for Revit 2016, which is passing a PowerShell command line after Revit has been launched, so what I am trying to figure out now, is how to pass this PowerShell command to Revit 2016 to a particular session, without affecting other sessions. This is the PowerShell line:

```
$Process = Get-Process Revit; $Process.ProcessorAffinity=255
```

So with this PowerShell command line, I was able to pick point which cores I can use with Revit 2016. Next step would be to incorporate this in my form, but as you would already know, if I pass this at any point, this will affect other "Revit.exe" sessions, and bring them to the same cores I specified in the command line. SO I had to think of a way to differentiate the processes of Revit from each other by the PID, and greatly vb.net makes it simple by using this:

```
myProcess.Id
```

and with this code:

```
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2016\Revit.exe"
myProcess.Start()
TextBox1.Text = myProcess.Id
```

I was able to accomplish, opening Revit, and capturing its PID. My question would be, how do I make a use of the process ID for a specific session and pass that PowerShell command to that process which I just started with that specific ID?

Comment: Personally, I would suggest using `System.Diagnostics.Process.ProcessorAffinity`. There's no need for interop between .NET and PS. (Though on my computer, your traditional `cmd` way works on RVT 2016/2017)

Comment: That is really weird! I have tried the conventional CMD way on RVT 2016 and it won't budge! Do you think it is a matter of RVT service pack?  what do you have installed so I can replicate it on my system. Thanks! @KeyuGan